# About Pymongo Mulitiprocessing

Tags: python, mongodb, multiprocessing

I want to use multiprocessing in insert operations in pymongo. In pymongo documentation it covers

https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html#bulk-insert

Bulk_Insert Operation. it says.

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> db = pymongo.MongoClient().bulk_example
>>> db.test.insert_many([{'i': i} for i in range(10000)]).inserted_ids
[...]
>>> db.test.count_documents({})
10000
```

Does insert_many operation inherently supports multiprocessing? If I want to you multiprocessing in insert operation for pymongo, is the code in

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41105328/7532444

this answer the best?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing and bulk operations are, in a way, opposites.

Multiprocessing is used to split the work across many parallel processes.

Bulk operations are used to combine several operations into one.

It therefore does not make sense to try to use the two together. One could use multiprocessing to parallelize database operations, and each of the processes could use bulk operations, but it doesn't make sense to try to apply multiprocessing to a single bulk request.